# Accessing first item from array returned by async-await REST call returning undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, async-await

I am using async await to make a REST API call that returns an array of single item. The `saveProduct` returns an array. When I try to extract the first item from the array while calling `saveProduct`, I get back undefined.

```
saveProduct(product: Product): Promise<Product[]> {
    return firstValueFrom(
        this._httpService.requestCall(this._url, ApiMethod.POST, product)
    );
}

const newProduct: Product = await this._productService.saveProduct(product)[0];

console.log(newProduct) => undefined

const newProduct: Product = await this._productService.saveProduct(product);

console.log(newProduct[0]) => properly prints the product object
```

Comment: You are trying to get the first element outside the asynchronous call. You need to wait first and then get elements from the array.

Comment: From time to time I see async- await codes relating to angular generally. I don't really understand why. Use an observable. This is the angular way.